# Why does my web reference to a remote asmx service not allow me to access operations?

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-4.5, web-reference

Trying to consume a remote asmx web service from server side code - from within a SignalR hub class to be specific.

After I add the reference it appears in my solution explorer under my main project.  If I right click and view the reference in object browser I see a long list of EventHandler's and EventArgs (but no ops) on the left.  In the middle of the list is the remote service name.  If I click on that, I do see the remote service operations listed in a pane to the right.  I just can't seem to reference them in the SignalR class file.

When I start typing the reference name in the SignalR file, code complete shows me the rest.  But from there I can't get at the operations.

Is there some setting when creating the reference that accounts for this lack of access?

**UPDATE:**

Appears to be an Intellisense problem?  When I started typing the snippet below it code completed the first part - "ThirdPartyService", so it was aware of the reference.  But it gave me nothing after that.  If I typed out the rest it underlined in red the soap client part and told me it didn't know what that was.

```
    //Call third party service
    ThirdPartyService.thirdPartySoapClient client = new ThirdPartyService.thirdPartySoapClient();
    client.operation(param1, param2, param3);
```

I removed and added the service reference a few times with no effect.  Finally I opened the source of the reference, added a few spaces and saved.  That seems to have jump started something.  Service method call is not working but at least it is now compiling and Intellisense is working.

Setting a break point I can see the service method call is being reached and the parameters contain correct data.  Watching in fiddler, however, I don't see a request being made when the method call line is reached and executed.  No errors are reported.  Hmmmm...  This is really kind of a separate issue maybe worthy of a separate post.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your serverside code, van you post soms code snippers?

Comment: There may, in fact, be.  I am studying this now and will post something soon.  Want to make sure I have a good handle on it so I can post effectively.

Comment: @Robert ask this question on Jabbr. It's where the SignalR community is. I'm sure they know it.